# Trying to write a systemd service file that can start commands as different users

Tags: systemd, configuration

I am looking for a way to have a generic systemd service file that can start its command as a user defined in an external file. This would allow me to start different server instances as different users, but without have multiple versions of the same thing.

I tried

```
[Service]
Type=forking
# Specify the level of the myserver instances on this host.
EnvironmentFile=/data/myserver/instances/LEVEL
EnvironmentFile=/data/myserver/instances/%i/USER
ExecStart=/sbin/daemonize /data/myserver/bin/start.sh %i ${LEVEL}
ExecStop=/data/myserver/bin/stop.sh %i
User=$USER
```

where I had this in the Environment File

```
USER=user1
```

It looks like $USER is evaluated before the EnvironmentFile is read. Is something like the following acceptable?

```
[Service]
Type=forking
# Specify the level of the myserver instances on this host.
EnvironmentFile=/data/myserver/instances/LEVEL
EnvironmentFile=/data/myserver/instances/%i/USER
ExecStart=/sbin/daemonize /bin/sudo -u $USER /data/myserver/bin/start.sh %i ${LEVEL}
ExecStop=/data/myserver/bin/stop.sh %i
User=root
```

Comment: That seems fine, although I would suggest getting rid of `/sbin/daemonize` and using `Type=simple`.

Comment: Thanks - I've had so many problems with setting the Type that forking always seems to be the best one.

Answer (score 1):

Systemd supports instantiated services that use templated service unit files.  See "SERVICE TEMPLATES" at: https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/systemd.service.5.html.

A prime example of this would be VNC service template unit files (as installed by TigerVNC Server).  Here is an example for OpenVPN: https://fedoramagazine.org/systemd-template-unit-files/

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm already using template files, since I have something like myserver@instance1.service and myserver@instance2.service. I could use myserver@user1-instance1.service, but I don't see a way to "parse" %i into different pieces.

Comment: Could you not parameterize the user in the service unit, and then have the LEVEL in the environment file?  Then your start.sh script could refer to $LEVEL directly, without needing it as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up with was

```
[Service]
Type=forking
# Run as user1 by default
Environment='USER=user1'
# Specify the level of the myserver instances on this host.
EnvironmentFile=/data/myserver/instances/LEVEL
# Allow the specific instance to override the level
EnvironmentFile=-/data/myserver/instances/%i/LEVEL
# Possibly override who this runs as
EnvironmentFile=-/data/myserver/instances/%i/USER
ExecStart=/sbin/daemonize -u $USER /data/myserver/bin/start.sh %i ${LEVEL}
ExecStop=/bin/su - $USER -c '/data/myserver/bin/stop.sh %i'
User=root
```